# Що таке "дутель"?

Tags: значення-слів, фразеологізми

Наткнувся на фразеологізм "дутеля з'їсти", однак не можу знайти визначення самого слова "дутель", в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/dutelj) бачимо:

> ДУ́ТЕЛЬ, я, чол.: ◊ Дутеля з'їсти (із'їсти) — умерти.

Що ж таке той "дутель" і чого, якщо його з'їсти, то можна померти???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Дутель](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)

- Словарь української мови: в 4-х тт. / За ред. Б. Грінченка. — К., 1907—1909. — Т. 1. — С. 458.

  > Ду́тель, ля, м. Пустой орѣхъ. Дутеля взяв. Черк. у. Ду́теля ззі́сти. Умереть.
- Жайворонок В. В. Знаки української етнокультури: Словник-довідник. — К.: Довіра, 2006. — С. 208.

  > ду́тель — порожній горіх; фра­зеологізм: ду́теля з’ї́сти — вмерти.

Новішиј СУМ-20 вже має так:

> [ДУ́ТЕЛЬ, я](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=25393&page=842), *ч.*, *рідко*. Порожній горіх.

Comment: Цікаво, що це за порожній горіх і чому людина помирає, якщо його з'їсть.